# How to connect to Oracle Database Server from another Database server?

Tags: oracle, remote-access

Server 1: Oracle 12.2 (Linux)

Server 2: Oracle 11g (Windows)

Problem Statement: Connect to Server 1 and take a full backup of the running database?

First, what are the requirements to connect to a database such as tnsname.ora file strings.

Second, how to take backup in already created directory on server 1 using server 2.

Comment: another machine is a database server too ? or just a client ?

Comment: You have given no indication of what you have tried or what issues you may be facing.  We cannot guess where your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

If On client-side Oracle Full Database or Oracle Client has already installed.
Locate TNSNAMES.ORA from one of the client-side servers and add below-mentioned string:

```
PRODDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = WIN-ORACLE-EN-1)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = PRODDB)
    )
  )
```

You also need to make sure that the LISTENER.ORA has been configured correctly and that both database and listener services are running.

After installing SQL*plus or SQL Developer, also make sure that on the client machine the TNSNAMES.ORA matches the server configuration, then try:

```
TNSPING PRODDB
```